# Facebook Connect and CakePHP - with or without CakePHP auth?

Tags: cakephp, facebook, authentication

I'm building a web application using CakePHP (which I'm new to). The app is going to require some sort of login where I'm going to use Facebook Connect. I've got a table for storing names, emails etc (for newsletter purposes etc) but not any password.

My question is: do/should I use CakePHP Auth combined with the Facebook Connect plugin (http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/229/CakePHP_Facebook_Plugin_Auth_Facebook_and_more) or should I just use the plugin without any CakePHP auth? What makes the most sense?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a straight answer to this, but I guess it depends on your users. Some people still feel uneasy logging in with their facebook accounts, worrying about what you will do with their valuable facebook data. If you're not worried about that, just use facebook connect, if you are, use both native and facebook connect.

If you choose to use both, you can generate a random password for the facebook connected accounts, which they will never use, since the login with facebook.

Hope this helps.